# Adding Service Reference with SSL

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, iis, certificate

I have a service with the following binding:

```
<bindings>
  <mexHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="MetadataHTTPSBinding" />
  </mexHttpsBinding>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHTTPSBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyNameSpace.PDFGenerator">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHTTPSBinding" name="DataEndpoint" contract="MyNameSpace.IPDFGenerator" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Whenever I use the WCF Test client, the service adds fine. Whenever I visit the service URL in IE, it is not displaying in errors or warnings about the certificate not being trusted. However, I am still getting a problem whenever I try to add the service within visual studio in the Add Service Reference dialog.

> There was an error downloading
>   '*baseurl*/services/PDFGenerator.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   '*baseurl*/services/PDFGenerator.svc'. An error occurred while making
>   the HTTP request to *baseurl*/services/PDFGenerator.svc. This could be
>   due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly
>   with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

Comment: If you change the bindings to http what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to change the URL when adding the service. I was doing the following

```
myservername/services/PDFGenerator.svc
```

but it needed to be

```
myservername.mycompany.com/services/PDFGenerator.svc
```

I don't understand why it needed that to work properly.